# Extjs application with Json-server not working fine

Tags: json, rest, extjs, sencha-cmd

I have a small app and I am using Rest Proxy. I set up json-server https://github.com/typicode/json-server locally.

I have not changed anything in server settings. I am able to successfully GET data from server but when I try to create data like this

```
var people = App.model.myModel;

var ed = new people({"id": 2,"title": "test","body": "test"});
ed.save();
```

Error appears in browser console is

> PUT http://localhost:3000/posts/11?_dc=1427464731634 404 (Not Found)

Can some one point out why it is trying to PUT data and not POST data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PUT is used to update an item, Not Create.

As you have specified an id value ExtJs will presume that you need to update the record rather than create it, therefore making the PUT request.

Most RESTful API's will provide GET, PUT, POST and sometimes DELETE, LINK Endpoints for each entity.

Comment: You are absolutely right . I figured out this my self as well. I will accept your answer as correct cause it explains issue in a better way

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem my self. I was sending the "id" as well and it was looking for a post with Id 2, and obviously that doesn't exist.

```
var people = App.model.myModel;
var ed = new people({"title": "test","body": "test"});
ed.save();
```

Works perfectly